# Unwanted line chart ''shadow" using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts which is an Angular charting module based on Chart.js. I am facing an issue where there are unwanted "shadow" kind of while rendering the chart as shown in the screen shot. I wonder if there is any chart option that I need to tweak on in order to remove it.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbpKr.png)

Comment: please provide more info adding the code here

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of it by setting stacked option to false